# Classification with custom utility function

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I have a problem which involves optimization of actions over time:

- Lets assume I have a set of input variables `X` where each `X_i_t` has a
  value at each point in time `t = 0 ... T`.
- For each point in time, I would like to choose an action `a_t` of a set of
  actions `A`,
- such that a utility function `U(a0, ..., a_T)` is maximized.

Note, the utility function does not have a closed-form solution and its value depends on the entire sequence of actions `a_0 ... a_T`.

**How would I implement something like this?** I am perfectly happy with a keyword I can use to look up relevant literature. I do not need a full solution. - Though if somebody can point me to a python sklearn function which does this, I would definitly not say no...

My first intuition was "logistic regression" but there is no way to assign "correct labels" to an action `a_t` at time `t`, since the utility depends on the actions taken earlier and later in the time series.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use neural networks with TensorFlow or Pytorch, it will be easy. As long as you can express the function `U` within the framework and the utility function is reasonably close to being continuous, you can back-propagate the utility to the network. You just ask the optimizer to maximize the utility and that's it.

If the utility function is discrete, it gets tricky, but there are several tricks you might try. One of them is the [REINFORCE algorithm](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tingwuwang/REINFORCE.pdf) (Monte-Carlo policy gradient). Another trick that is getting quite popular is [Gubmle softmax](https://casmls.github.io/general/2017/02/01/GumbelSoftmax.html) that allows sampling of discrete action and propagating the error to the network.

If you plan to use different classifiers (like decision forests or whatever), you might try something based on imitation learning like the [SEARN algorithim](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0786).